# Dental technician jobs in NL

Tags: working-visas, netherlands

What is the requirements to work in Netherlands as dental technician? 
I am Syrian living in Iraq, having an experience with ten years at dental technology including cad/cam, fixed and removable restoration.
So I’m asking about the requirements to have visa that allow me to work in Netherlands, as a Syrian resident in Europe.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? Eg https://www.government.nl/topics/new-in-the-netherlands/employment-permits-for-foreign-nationals